# How to work with request.post() method without waiting for response

Tags: python-3.x, api, request

Hi i am new to python development.

i have to make multiple push in very short amount of time(seconds preferably).

currently i am using request package's post method to post the data into an API .
But , by default request method waits for the response from the API.

```
requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Is there any other way that i can post the data into API in asynchronous way ?

Thank you

Comment: @OferSadan there question there is for to get the content from the request object . The title is misleading

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are not interested in response from the server(fire and forget) then you can use [an async library](https://pypi.org/project/requests-async/) for this. But I must warn you, you cannot mix sync and async code(actually you can but it's not worth dealing with it) so most of your codes must be changed.

Another approach is using threads, they can call the `url` seperately wait for the response without affecting rest of your code.

Something like this will help:

```
def request_task(url, json, headers):
    requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)


def fire_and_forget(url, json, headers):
    threading.Thread(target=request_task, args=(url, json, headers)).start()

...

fire_and_forget(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

**Brief info about threads**

Threads are seperate flow of execution. Multiple threads run concurrently so when a thread is started it runs seperately from current execution. After starting a thread, your program just continue to execute next instructions while the instructions of thread also executes concurrently. For more info, I recommend [realpython introduction to threads](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: ,Could you please explain me the use of threading.Thread there ?

Comment: @SumanthShetty it's not easy to explain threads in an answer, you should follow the link I provided in the answer to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: @SumanthShetty, if this solved your issue, please consider to click the green checkbox to make it an accepted answer, so others know it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for not just recommending Celery as a silver bullet like everybody else and for providing such a clean and simple example. This was the perfect solution for my use case.

Comment: this is a simple solution, no grequests, no asyncio, no celery or rabbitmq, thanks.